# How to update a date type column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

We want to update the dates in this example database to seem more recent.  Increase each Quarter code by 5 years so 19964 will look like 20014.  Verify your result by showing the data in the table. I am using the mySQL Oracle CommandLine Client and would like to know how to update all interviewdate records by 5 years.

```
interview table
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| interviewdate | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

interviewdate column
+---------------+
| interviewdate |
+---------------+
| 1995-06-01    |
| 1995-06-01    |
| 1995-06-30    |
| 1995-06-30    |
| 1995-07-01    |
| 1995-08-01    |
| 1995-08-01    |
| 1995-08-02    |
| 1995-12-01    |
| 1995-12-02    |
| 1995-12-04    |
| 1996-01-21    |
| 1996-02-01    |
| 1996-02-02    |
| 1996-07-01    |
| 1996-07-01    |
| 1996-08-01    |
| 1996-08-08    |
| 1996-08-11    |
| 1997-01-01    |
| 1997-01-01    |
| 1997-01-31    |
| 1997-02-01    |
| 1997-03-24    |
| 1997-03-31    |
| 1997-04-20    |
| 1997-04-22    |
| 1997-05-01    |
+---------------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE interview
SET qtrcode = DATEADD(year, 5, qtrcode);
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION jobs.DATEADD does not exist
```

Comment: See [the MySQL date function reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: I did, the answer of what I did try is on the bottom.

Comment: Sorry - Looks like you are using a `DATEADD()` function from MS Access.  MySQL's is `DATE_ADD()` (linked above)  as in `DATE_ADD(interviewdate, INTERVAL 5 year)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
update interview
set interviewdate = date_add(interviewdate, interval 5 year);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55ab7/1